# How to write Mysql query to compare variable value with column values and get top highest record or second highest record

Tags: mysql

I have table in mysql with few records, so I want to compare value with price column.

1. if passing value from variable is less than price column value then get second highest record with product id ="p1"
2. if passing value from variable is greater then price column values then get top highest record  with product id= "p1"

This my table

```
id  product price
1   p1    2000
2   p2    3000
3   p3    4000
4   p1    2500
```

if we want to compare ' price ' column with value $var='1800' and product="p1" then output should be second highest record because variable value is less than price column value

output :

```
id  product  price
1    p1      2000
```

but if we pass value $var=5000 for price column  and product="p1" then

output should be :

```
id  product  price
4    p1       2500
```

Comment: What will be the output when input variable is 2200 and product is p1. Now one product has price (=2500) higher than 2200, and another has price (=2000) lower than 2200.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya  if input variable is 2200 and product is p1 then get for 2500 price

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,product INT NOT NULL
,price INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,2000),
(2,2,3000),
(3,3,4000),
(4,1,2500);

mysql> SELECT *, ABS(price-1800) x FROM my_table WHERE product = 1 ORDER BY x LIMIT 1;
+----+---------+-------+-----+
| id | product | price | x   |
+----+---------+-------+-----+
|  1 |       1 |  2000 | 200 |
+----+---------+-------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT *, ABS(price-5000) x FROM my_table WHERE product = 1 ORDER BY x LIMIT 1;
+----+---------+-------+------+
| id | product | price | x    |
+----+---------+-------+------+
|  4 |       1 |  2500 | 2500 |
+----+---------+-------+------+
```

Comment: but when I pass value 2200 it is getting record 2000 but I want record should be 2500

Comment: can you please suggest me query which should work like if value is 1800 then get price column 2000 but if value is 2200 or 5500 then get price column for 2500

Comment: Not without knowing the general logic behind such a choice